# Сверстать элемент страницы

Tags: css3, html5

[image: элемент, который нужно сверстать]

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно сверстать элемент представленный выше. В фотошопе видно, что `font-size` кавычек равен `337px`. Проблема в том, что тогда создается огромный отступ вниз и небольшой уже вверх, из-за чего сама надпись "Dhavan" поднимается высоко. Пытался заключить в ограничивающий контейнер эти кавычки. Примерный код:

```css
 .quote-jail {
 position: relative;
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.quote {
 font-size: 337px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -35px;
 left: -25px;

}
 .name {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 26px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-jail">
 <span class="name">dhavan</span>
 <span class="quote"> &#8221;</span>
</div>
```

Затем круглое изображение и этот `quote-jail` поместил в блок, которому задал `flex-direction: row`. Но мне кажется, такой подход неверный. Очень настораживают отрицательные top/left. Все ли я правильно сделал и есть ли другой, альтернативный способ наверстать это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При увеличении размера шрифта увеличивается и line-height, отсюда эти ненужные отступы. Попробуйте уменьшить line-height вплоть до 0.

Если не поможет, просто вставьте кавычки в вёрстку как png-картинку и не заморачивайтесь :)